# Referencing line numbers in an algorithm

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms

Referencing figures is simple:

```
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Blah blah blah blah blah}
    \label{fig:name}
    %shtuff goes here
\end{figure}

See figure~\ref{fig:name}.
```

I would like to know if it is possible to reference line numbers in an algorithm, e.g.:

```
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State blah1
    \State blah2 \label{lst:line:blah2}
    \State blah3
\end{algorithmic}

As you can see on line~\ref{lst:line:blah2} \ldots
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Of course you can; here's a simple example based on your code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State blah1
    \State blah2 \label{lst:line:blah2}
    \State blah3
\end{algorithmic}

As you can see on line~\ref{lst:line:blah2} \ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't even try it out, I just assumed it would be more difficult. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: How can I label it for multiple lines?

Comment: You and me both @knpwrs , and 55 people with us.