# Jump to a line number in an algorithm

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms, algorithmic

My question is basically a follow up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47664/referencing-line-numbers-in-an-algorithm).
I would like to be able to click on the reference and have the PDF viewer jump to the specific line, so that the line it the top most line on screen. Especially for ever long algorithms this would be very useful.

Thank you very much in advance!

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

As you can see on line~\ref{alg:l2}

\clearpage

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State statement
    \State statement \label{alg:l2}
    \State statement
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\clearpage

More text

\end{document}
```