# Reference to a line in an algorithm using algpseudocode

Tags: cross-referencing, algpseudocode

When I want to reference to a line using algpseudocode, clicking the links given by `\ref` send me to the beginning of the algorithm instead of sending me to the line in question.

Do you know whether there exist a way to have the second behavior (I know this is the case with algorithmic) ?
If so, how to do it ?

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  % linkcolor=teal,
  % filecolor=blue,
  % citecolor=cyan,
  % urlcolor=violet,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My algorithm}
  \label{algo:example}
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State \label{line:1} Lots of line...
    \State Line 2
    \State Line 3
    \State Line 4
    \State Line 5
    \State Line 6
    \State Line 7
    \State Line 8
    \State Line 9
    \State \label{line:10}Line 10
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

Line \ref{line:1} and \ref{line:10} reference different lines but both point to the beginning of the algorithm when I click on the links.

\end{document}
```

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632811/jump-to-a-line-number-in-an-algorithm